# How to download file from deployed server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Can someone tell me why function below properly download my file from server when i work locally (by localhost) but not download me and return me `500 internal server error` when i try do is when i deploy my app on remote server?

```
    async downloadFile(fileId: number): Promise<Buffer> {
        const fileName = await this.getFileName(fileId);

        const fileBuffer = await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '/files/' + fileName + '.xlsx', {}, (err, data) => {
              if (err) reject(err)
              else resolve(data)
            });
          });
        
        return fileBuffer ;
    }
```

thanks for any help

EDIT, ERROR FROM LOG:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Comment: HTTP erros codes provide little information. Check your error logs. What is the internal server error?

Comment: Not the correct answer but you should be using a readable stream; dont read the hole file into the memory

Comment: @MarkBaijens i add error from logs at the bottom

Comment: That error is pretty clear right? The path to the file does not lead to an existing file.

Comment: @ertyjdjgdfgj - have you verified the file is there on the remote server?

Comment: You should debuglog the resuts of process.cwd() and check if your working directory on the server is as expected. If your /files/ directory is in the directory of the code fragment above you should use __dirname.

Comment: Yes, files is in directory but only download me when i work locally

Comment: What does the file of your file relates to ? The javascript file itself ?

Comment: no, its file in xlsx format

Comment: if I using typescript and nestjs, then my directory must go to `dist` directory?

Comment: You got me wrong process.cwd relates to the *node process* working dir. meaning that if the project is deployed on a different file system this value will change

Comment: as a consequence you should not rely on this value. code should be able to run wherever you deploy it

Comment: so, what i must change?

Comment: @ertyjdjgdfgj alright. see answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to access your file relatively to your script dir you should use [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Also using the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module in order to build your file location in a platform agnostic way is a good practice.

```js
const path = require('path')

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'files', `${fileName}.xlsx`)
```

`process.cwd()` refers to you *node process* working dir. Using it in your context would tie your code to how the entry point has been called. This is bad. Code should not have to be aware of its execution context to work whenever this is possible.

An even better way would be to make your file location configurable (using an environment variable or a config file) and pass your download folder value to your code this way.

see https://12factor.net/config

example

```js
const baseDir = process.env.FILES_PATH || '/some/default/location';
const filePath = path.join(baseDir, 'files', `${fileName}.xlsx`);
```

then run your program with

```sh
FILES_PATH=/your/directory node your_script.js
```

Comment: my `files` folder must be at this same directory like my class when is this function?

Comment: @ertyjdjgdfgj added an edit with a another way of handling things

Comment: ok, but right now i save my file int `src/.../files` directory but `__dirname` want to get my file from `dist/.../files` directory, why? and why i do not have my `files` folder into dist?

Comment: i not deployed my project yet, i try use this locally and return me that i do not have file or directory in my dist folder

Comment: @ertyjdjgdfgj well maybe give a try to the second - preferable IMHO - way (I've edited the answer with an example)